# How to evaluate the following triple integral

Tags: integration

We have the following triple integral:
$$\iiint z \mathrm dz \mathrm d y\mathrm d x$$ where $\sqrt x+\sqrt y + \sqrt z \leq 1$
I tried to find the intersection of the surface defined by the above equation with the three axis: so the region will be:

$0 \lt x \lt 1$, 
$0 \lt y \lt 1-\sqrt x$, and
$0 \lt z \lt 1-\sqrt(y)$

So we get $$\int_0^{1}\int_0^{1-\sqrt x}\int_0^{1-\sqrt y}zdzdydx$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite correct. For $0 \le x \le 1$, you have the slice $0 \le \sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} \le 1-\sqrt{x}$, which you can describe as $0 \le y \le (1-\sqrt{x})^2$ and $0 \le z \le (1-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$.

You may also try the change of variables $u=\sqrt{x}$, $v=\sqrt{y}$, $w=\sqrt{z}$ to get a simpler domain of integration.

Comment: Thank you Mr Hans, Can you please give more details

Comment: @Freshman42: Yes, if you try to specify what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand how to get the limits of the integrals

Comment: @Freshman42: Yes, that was of course the question to begin with. But I don't know how you were thinking when you came up with your own suggestion, and I don't know at what step of my explanation you're getting stuck, so I don't know what extra information I need to include to make it clearer.